# Using the security definition in the malicious model to prove security in the semi honest model

Tags: protocol-design, protocol-analysis, security-definition

Can I use the security definition in the malicious model in order to prove the security of a two-party protocol which is in the semi-honest model? (I am using IDEAL/REAL Model paradigm)

Would you please explain it to me?

These definitions are from "Efficient Secure Two-Party Protocols-Hazay-Lindell"
**Definition 2.3.1** (Malicious model)

[image]

**Definition 2.2.1** (Semi honest model)

[image]

-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this, because, as explained further in the book, security against malicious adversaries does not imply security against semi-honest ones.